# Why do I get different responses either when I use `sudo` before `kubectl` or not?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, ports

For example when I use `kubectl get pods` the response is:

```
No resources found in default namespace.
```

But when I use `sudo kubectl get pods` the result is:

```
E1211 12:01:15.409201   50965 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
E1211 12:01:15.409569   50965 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
E1211 12:01:15.411086   50965 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
E1211 12:01:15.412633   50965 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
E1211 12:01:15.414189   50965 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

PS: From my previous knowledge I think when I use `kubectl` without `sudo`, it refers to `192.168.1.2:6443` but with the `sudo` word it is looking for `localhost:8080`. I don't know why?

Answer (score 2):

I think you haven't configured kubeconfig in root user.

**The sudo command allows you to run programs with the security privileges of another user.**

When you run `sudo kubectl` you're running `kubectl` with root user and most probably you might have not configured kubeconfig for root user.

Answer (score 0):

This is only loosely related to your question, but if `kubectl get pods` gives:

```
No resources found in default namespace.
```

check `kubectl get namespaces` and then re-run the query with `kubectl get pods -n <namespace>`